# to find an error in C strings

Tags: c++, string

I had an inverview today, and was asked to write a function of two strings concatenation. But after I've finished, I've heard, that generally the code is ok, but I've done a little error there. Checked it at home, but everything is working. Whats the problem?

```
char * strconcat (char *S1, char *S2){
    char *S3 = new char [strlen(S1) + strlen(S2) +1];
    strcpy(S3, S1);
    strcat(S3, S2);
    return S3;   
}
```

Comment: Using `new` like that is neither idiomatic C nor C++.

Comment: This is an odd hybrid of C and C++. What specific guidelines were you given? If I was asked that question, as a C++ question, I'd answer: `std::string concat(const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2) { return s1 + s2; }` Your code is quick, dirty and "probably good enough most of the time". It's not written the way I would expect someone trying to show me that he knows how to code would write it.

Comment: Maybe because you're not checking for null pointers?

Comment: also in interviews it is better to use wchar_t version. It just shows global thinking

Comment: @David Schwartz
error at return s1 + s2; no operator '+' matches these operands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char * strconcat (char *S1, char *S2){
    if(S1 == NULL || S2 == NULL)
         return NULL;
    int S1_len = strlen(S1);
    int S2_len = strlen(S2);
    char *S3 = new char [S1_len + S2_len +1];
    memset(S3, 0, S1_len + S2_len +1);
    strcpy(S3, S1);
    strcat(S3, S2);  // or memcpy(S3+S1_len, S2, S2_len);
    return S3;   
}
```

Comment: why have u added memset here, after allocating memory with new

Answer (score 5):

Well ... It's all about the requirements and quality expectations, I guess.

A few things:

- The input pointers should be `const`.
- You don't handle `new[]` failing (it will throw an exception though, which might be fine).
- For performance, it's best not to do the `strcpy()`/`strcat()` sequence, since you spend more time than necessary walking strings.
- Stylistically, it's a bit "off". It reads a lot like C code, but uses C++ constructs.

Answer (score 2):

Besides writing C code (minus the `new`), your code doesn't work everywhere it's expected, for example:

```
char* hellowWorld = strconcat("Hello ", "world!");
```

If you can't tell directly why this doesn't work, try compiling - the error will give you a hint.

Comment: Yes, it seems to work, but of course, the returned pointer needs to be deleted after used.

Comment: it gives me warnings about using strcpy_s and strcat_s instead of strcpy/strcat, after all it all works

Answer (score 0):

Looking like you mixed up both C, C++ style in coding. Also the way you try to use new is not the standard way. Either you can make it pure C way or C++ way.

It seems like, they are treating style as error, although it is working.But you can't predict interviewer's mind.